# Is there a simple way to get a NodeJS object consumable by SQL Server and/or .net?

Tags: .net, node.js, sql-server, amazon-web-services, image-manipulation

I have a SQL Server 2017 database and a series of .net APIs that consume the stored procedures exposed from the database. This works fine for posting data from a website/mobile app and reading that data back. However, one of my pages, a registration page, needs to do more. It takes the usual, name, email, telephone etc and this is all good. It also takes a document as an image. The image uploads fine and is stored in the database. I want to be able to "read" that image though and extract specific parts.

For example, let's assume the image is a drivers licence. I know that the image should contain a headshot and various other key bits of info such as name, issuing date, reference number etc.

I want to be able to read the information from the image. I know there are pitfalls to this, and extracting the photo might be a step too far, but I want the app to extract the text so that I can verify it's what I'm expecting. If it matches, it's a pass. If it matches, say 90%, it gets quarantined for manual verification, and anything less than this is rejected. I'm actually hoping to get two processes, the one described above and another process that checks a second image to ensure that it's appropriate content (i.e. not porn).

I have a developer working on a tool that connects to the AWS Rekognition service which seems to do exactly what I need, but he's writing this in NodeJS.

So, my questions are:
1) Can this be compiled through Visual Studio into something that the .net website and mobile apps can work with?
2) If so, I'm assuming this would be a dll, can I then use that dll in a SQL Server CLR so the database can consume it too?

If the answers to these are no, is there another solution? Could I, for example, publish the NodeJS app exposing an API so it can be consumed that way?

My ultimate aim is to be able to check and extract the data from the image, so if there is a better solution using a different approach, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0):

You dont want to be doing heavy image processing in your primary database server.

You'd normally want to place that kind of load on an application tier that would queue up a recognition process upon receiving the new registration.

In a simpler environment, just treat your web server as application tier, and queue up the process either asynchronously with result reporting into a session variable or the database itself with a polling or push notification mechanism for reporting the result.

You probably want to modify your requirement to your subcontracter to do this within .NET ecosystem instead of using nodejs.

There are nodejs/net bridges, one of which is called Edge.Net  Tricky part can be hosting the node runtime within your NET process, or having to marshal calls into the node process.  Edge.Net might automatically assist with this.

Comment: Thanks enorl76, I am having the processing done in the application tier. The actual heavy lifting is done by AWS. We'll already be limiting the size of the image so the load to AWS is small, and the interface will always be either via the mobile app (with the image sent to the NodeJS tool there) or via the website (with it doing to the same) The CLR process would be as a back up, but even then, it would just be a call to the AWS service via the CLR.

Comment: I'll take a look at Edge.Net. If that does the job, that might be the solution. The developer doesn't have the .net skills, so if Edge.Net isn't viable for us, we might be back to the drawing board.